# How to mock static method using powermock?

Tags: java, junit, aem, powermock

```
public class DownloadBoxHelper extends WCMUsePojo {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DownloadBoxHelper.class);
private ArrayList<Map<String, String>> downloadList;
private ArrayList<Map<String, String>> downloadListFinal;
DownloadBoxModel downloadBoxModel;
@Override
public void activate() throws Exception {
    log.info("Download Box activate Method started");
    JcrUtilService jcrUtil = getSlingScriptHelper().getService(JcrUtilService.class);

    downloadBoxModel = getResource().adaptTo(DownloadBoxModel.class);
    downloadList = downloadBoxModel.getDownloadList();
    downloadListFinal =DHLUtil.getSizeTypeOfAsset(downloadList, getResource(), jcrUtil);
    downloadBoxModel.setDownloadListFinal(downloadListFinal);
    log.info("Download Box activate Method Ended");
}

public DownloadBoxModel getDownloadBoxModel() {

    return downloadBoxModel;
}
```

}

I want to mock this helper class. But this helper class have some static method like **downloadListFinal =DHLUtil.getSizeTypeOfAsset(downloadList, getResource(), jcrUtil);**
This static method refer to DHLUtil.class file. Here is declaration

```
**public static ArrayList<Map<String, String>> getSizeTypeOfAsset(ArrayList<Map<String, String>> downloadList,
        Resource rs, JcrUtilService jcrUtil) {
    log.info("DHLUtil getSizeTypeOfAsset() initiated ");
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> localDownloadList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    Session session = null;
    Node assetMetaNode;
    try {
        session = jcrUtil.getSession(DHLSubService.readservice);
        Iterator<Map<String, String>> it = downloadList.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map<String, String> mp = it.next();
            if (mp.get(DHLConstants.ASSET_DOWNLOAD_ITEM).toString().contains(".")) {
                assetMetaNode = session.getNode((mp.get(DHLConstants.ASSET_DOWNLOAD_ITEM).toString())
                        + DHLConstants.SLASH + JcrConstants.JCR_CONTENT +DHLConstants.SLASH + DamConstants.ACTIVITY_TYPE_METADATA);
                String assetType = assetMetaNode.getProperty(DamConstants.DC_FORMAT).getString();
                if(assetType!=null){
                    if(assetType.contains("vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet") || assetType.contains("vnd.ms-excel")){
                        assetType="ms-excel";
                    }
                    if(assetType.contains("vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document") || assetType.contains("msword")){
                        assetType="ms-word";
                    }
                    if(assetType.contains("vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation") || assetType.contains("vnd.ms-powerpoint")){
                        assetType="ms-powerpoint";
                    }

                 }

                Property assetSize = assetMetaNode.getProperty(DamConstants.DAM_SIZE);
                double assetSizeUpdated = 0d;
                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.0");
                String assetSizeType = DHLConstants.BYTE;
                ;
                if (assetSize.getLong() < (1024)) {
                    assetSizeUpdated = (double) assetSize.getLong();
                }
                if (assetSize.getLong() > 1024 && assetSize.getLong() < (1024 * 1024)) {
                    assetSizeType = DHLConstants.KILOBYTE;
                    assetSizeUpdated = (double) assetSize.getLong() / 1024L;
                }
                if (assetSize.getLong() > (1024 * 1024)) {
                    assetSizeType = DHLConstants.MEGABYTE;
                    assetSizeUpdated = ((double) assetSize.getLong() / (1024 * 1024));
                }
                if (assetType.contains("/")) {
                    String strSplit[] = assetType.split("/");
                    assetType = strSplit[1];
                }
                String strMetaData = assetType.toUpperCase() + DHLConstants.SPACE + DHLConstants.LEFT_BRACKET
                        + DHLConstants.SPACE + df.format(assetSizeUpdated) + DHLConstants.SPACE + assetSizeType + DHLConstants.SPACE + DHLConstants.RIGHT_BRACKET;
                mp.put(DamConstants.ACTIVITY_TYPE_METADATA, strMetaData);
                localDownloadList.add(mp);
            }
        }
    }catch (DHLException dhe) {
        log.error("DHLException {}", dhe);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception {}", e);
    }finally {
        if(null!=session && session.isLive()) {
            session.logout();
        }
    }

    return localDownloadList;
}
```

So how I mock this?

My JUnit file is:

```
**@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
  @PrepareForTes({DownloadBoxHelper.class,DHLUtil.class,DownloadBoxModel.class})

public class DownloadBoxHelperTest extends PowerMockTestCase {
    private DownloadBoxHelper aFinalClass_mock = null;

     @Test
        public void mockFinalClassTest() {
         ArrayList<Map<String, String>> downloadList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();;
         ArrayList<Map<String, String>> downloadListFinal;
         Map<String, String> n = new HashMap<String, String>();
         n.put("a", "a");
         n.put("b", "b");
         downloadList.add(n);

            DownloadBoxModel downloadBoxModel;

            aFinalClass_mock = PowerMockito.mock(DownloadBoxHelper.class);
            Mockito.when(aFinalClass_mock.getSlingScriptHelper()).thenReturn(null);

            // Assert the mocked result is returned from method call
            //Assert.assertEquals(aFinalClass_mock.getSlingScriptHelper()).thenReturn(null);
        }

     @Test
        public void mockFinalClassTest_1() {
         JcrUtilService jcrUtil;s
         ArrayList<Map<String, String>> downloadListFinal;
         Map<String, String> n1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
         n1.put("a", "a");
         n1.put("b", "b");
         downloadListFinal.add(n1);


         Mockito.when(aFinalClass_mock.getDownloadListFinal()).thenReturn(downloadListFinal);
            // Assert the mocked result is returned from method call
            //Assert.assertEquals(aFinalClass_mock.getSizeTypeOfAsset(downloadListFinal, getResource(), jcrUtil);, mockedResult);
        }
```

Please Provide me solution or one reference JUnit file where we are using ["

```
public static ArrayList<Map<String, String>> getSizeTypeOfAsset(ArrayList<Map<String, String>> downloadList,
    Resource rs, JcrUtilService jcrUtil) {
log.info("DHLUtil getSizeTypeOfAsset() initiated "); "
```

] this type of class.

Thanks

Comment: Asking "provide me solution asap" isn't very polite; and the initial "please" doesn't really help there. And you know, the fact that you are dumping so much ugly formatted code on us ... isn't exactly inviting either. In other words: please turn to the helpcenter and see how to ask "stuff aint working" questions; and then try to build a **minimal** viable example showing your problem. Don't throw so much code at us and order results ASAP.

Comment: And just for the sake of it: using **static** methods simply makes your code hard to test. Although PowerMock might look like the correct answer to that problem ... well, it is not. Chances are that you will spent a lot of time hunting bizarre Powermock problems ... so, at least consider to the opposite thing. Meaning: redesin your production code to be **testable**; and then avoid using Powermock.

Comment: Please, check documentation before ask question https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage#mocking-static-method

Answer (score 4):

you should add:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(DHLUtil.class);
```

and the you can use this method like any other mock:

```
when(DHLUtil.getSizeTypeOfAsset()).thenReturn(whatever);
```